# Running average of time series containing NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the running average of a time series in Python which contains NaN values. I don't want to take into account these NaN values when calculating the running average, but I do want to take into account the correct spacing/window used for the running average. So when I want to take the running average over 5 data points including a NaN value, it should not take into account the NaN value when calculating the running average, but it should count the row of this datapoint in the window.

I'm now using `rolling(5).mean()`, but it looks like it doesn't work properly. Can someone explain to me how this works and what I should use?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.dropna()` on the data frame to remove the rows containing NaN values. The mean function returns the arithmetic mean for an axis in a data frame. [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-mean/) article has more info on the method.